# Pushing to current branch (that is not master/main) on a GitHub workflow triggered from a workflow_run

Tags: github, github-actions

I have two workflows, the first runs on dispatch and also on push and the second runs after the first workflow completes. In my repository, main is a protected branch and can only be merged from a PR so cannot be pushed directly onto. The intention of the repository is when new changes arrive on a new branch 'A', whether manually or from pushing to main run the first workflow which does a check on the changed files and if successful the second workflow starts automatically to compile a new file 'compiled.csv' from the existing files and to push 'compiled.csv' into main. But since main is protected, I am trying to push 'compiled.csv' to the A branch on which I ran the first workflow manually following which I can make a PR and merge 'compiled.csv' to main.

```
name: workflow 2
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: [workflow 1]
    types: [completed]
  push:
    branches:
      - '*'
      - '!main'
    paths:
      - 'example/**.csv'
jobs:
  compile_files:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Compile files
    steps:
      - name: Set up Python 3.x
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.x'

     - name: Checkout repo content
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.ref }}
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Run python script
        working-directory: ./src
        run: |
          python example.py     # Generates compiled.csv
          git config user.name github-actions
          git config user.email github-actions@github.com
          git add .
          git commit -m "Github Actions"
      
      # Push the committed changes to the branch that triggered the workflow
      - name: Push changes
        uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
        with:
          branch: ${{ github.ref }}
          force_with_lease: true
```

The issue I am having is that when workflow 2 runs, the action/checkout@v3 job automatically checks out to main and not branch A, this causes compiled.csv to not be pushed because of branch protection. I don't want to hard code the workflow to push to branch A but rather the triggering branch.

I've tried to use `ref: github.ref` but it still checks out to main even when I manually triggered workflow 1 from branch A, checking the workflow logs I can see workflow 1 checks out to branch A. I keep workflow 1 and 2 separate for modularity else I would consider joining them to solve this issue.

[workflow log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31uRi.png)

I also tried to play around with the branch ref in the 'ad-m/github-push-action@master' job to no avail. Any help is appreciated.